# Youtube api jar dependencies

Tags: java, youtube-api

I'm really stuck here.  I'm trying out the youtube API and just cannot get anything to run.  I'm having one classnotfound issue after another.

Right now I have the following jars on my classpath

- activation.jar
- gdata-client-1.0.jar
- gdata-core-1.0.jar
- gdata-media-1.0.jar
- gdata-youtube-2.0.jar
- guava-11.0.2.jar
- jsr305.jar
- mail.jar

And it is failing of a ClassNotFoundException on com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential when I try and create an instance of YouTubeService.  I tried looking up info, but all other answers are just too old.  Anyone here tried using Youtube API recently?  Ideally, I would just like a list of required jars.
I would prefer actual users of the API to respond.

Comment: Quick googling gives a sample : http://java.dzone.com/announcements/getting-started-youtube-java Wanna match your jars?

Comment: Have you actually tried that?  I have, and it didn't work.  It's also from 2010, which is pretty old.  It depends on some jars that are now depreciated such as google-collect-1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you needed an additional jar called google-oauth-client-1.9.0-beta.jar
As far as I can tell, it's not listed as a dependency or included along with the samples.